# Disabled dates are being selected by input in jQuery (multi)datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-multidatespicker

Im using the extension **Multidatespicker** for jquery Datepick. I have 2 calendars, the first one shows all the dates that were selected for this session (from the data base, via **addDates**) and the dates from the other sessions are disabled via (**addDisableDates**), as shown in the code below

```
$( "#datepickerAdvanced" ).multiDatesPicker({
  numberOfMonths: 3,
  defaultDate: today,
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  altField: '#altField',
  minDate: 0,
  maxDate: 180
    <?php if ($dates2 != "") { ?>
        ,addDates: dates2
        <?php } ?> 
        <?php if ($blockeddates != "") { ?>
        ,addDisabledDates: blockeddates
        <?php } ?>  
});
```

The other input lets you select a date and it fills automatically in the same day of the week for the number of weeks that the user wants the future dates.

```
$('#getdates').click(function(element) 
{
    var initdate = $("#datepick1").datepicker( "getDate" )
    var tempagendArray = [];

    var periodweeks = $('#period').val();
    var periodtimes = $('#vezes').val();

    for (i=0; i< periodtimes; i ++)
    {

        tempagendArray[i] = $('#datepick1').datepicker('getDate');  
        tempagendArray[i].setDate(tempagendArray[i].getDate()+7*periodweeks*i); 

    }

    $( "#datepickerAdvanced" ).multiDatesPicker('resetDates');
    $( "#datepickerAdvanced" ).multiDatesPicker({
            addDates: tempagendArray
        })


})
```

The dates are being filled successfully, my problem is that if a date is disabled, it fills that date anyway and there is no method to check if a date is disabled. Also there seems to be a bug where the today's date is also selected. Check this screenshot for better understanding: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LUpE.png

From the screenshot, the Initial Date is 28/01/2015 and the period selected is jumping 2 weeks for 4 times. Whats happening is that the date 26/01/2015 is also selected (today's date) and so are the disabled dates 11/02/2015 and 25/02/2015.

Comment: `tempagendArray[i].setDate(tempagendArray[i].getDate()+7*periodweeks*i)` – since your `for` loop starts with `i=0`, I’d say you are selecting today’s date here yourself. And if that plugins does not offer an option to not select disabled dates when you are explicitly feeding it dates via script, then you will have to implement that check yourself _before_ you put those dates into that array.

Comment: Thanks but when i=0, it gets the date of $("#datepick1") which is the initial date of the datepick input (below in the picture). Ive solved it by using $.inArray to compare the selected dates with the array of disabled dates (blockeddates) and I removed the today date using removeDate after the addDates.